# How to check if anything was inserted with INSERT SELECT (T-SQL)

Tags: t-sql, select, insert, rowcount

I have an insert statement:

```
insert into parentTbl
select firstId, secondId, thirdId, dateTm
from importTbl
where codeId = @codeIdParam
```

I need to reliably find out if that insert inserted anything at all.  Ideally, I would like to set a `@insertedCount` variable to the number of rows inserted, even if that is 0.

I am currently using:

```
set @insertedCount = @@ROWCOUNT
```

But that only seems to get the last number of inserted rows - the problem is that if the `INSERT SELECT` statement did not insert anything the `@@ROWCOUNT` does not return 0.

Comment: Is your insert statement resides within a loop or cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using an [`OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause, which would return one row per inserted row; something like:

```
insert into parentTbl
output inserted.firstId
select firstId, secondId, thirdId, dateTm
from importTbl
where codeId = @codeIdParam
```

This would give you a resultset with the `firstId`s of every inserted row, which you could then run a count on.
One way would be to `output into` a table-var, and then do a `select count(*) from @tableVar` at the end to get your insert-count.

Comment: Ultimately, I've taken the SELECT of the INSERT SELECT statement and set it to return COUNT(*) to a variable - though, of course, this happens before the INSERT SELECT, which is now wrapped in an IF block.